# Production Set: Not satisfying Free Disposal Assumption

Tags: microeconomics, production-function

I saw the figure which satisfies the free disposal assumption in Mas-Colell, Whinston and Green (1995), but wondering if there is a figure that DOES NOT satisfy the free disposal assumption? Any leads will be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is something you can figure out yourself. If you have not yet tried, I encourage you to do so.

---

Draw any set $H \in \mathbb{R}^n $. Select any point $x$ of set. Is the set of all points $y$ "under" this point $x$, that is
$$
\left\{y\in \mathbb{R}^n | y << x \right\},
$$
a subset of $H$? 
If no, free disposal is violated. 
If yes, remove any of these points from $H$. The reduced set now violates free disposal.

For a figure of such a set, you can consider the Mercedes logo:
[image]

Comment: definition: The ability to get rid of units of inputs and outputs free of cost.

Comment: No math definition?

Comment: y ∈ Y and y'≤ y, then y' ∈ y

Comment: Then it is not enough if "*all of that negative x axis and negative y axis is still possible*", is it?

Comment: So, given the definition, any further suggestions?

Comment: Other then the exact solution I've already given? No, no further suggestions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124273/discussion-between-alexa-thomas-and-giskard).